# How to figure out the status code for the rejection of the html template in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

How can I get the status code of the response - `401` in `$routeChangeError` and redirect to the correct route with AngularJS if the user is not authorized.

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, next, current, rejection) {
     var status = //how to get the status code?
     if(status===401) $location.path("/401");
});
```

I have a the following route :

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/office/workspaces", {
        templateUrl: "partials/office/workspaces",
        controller: "OfficeWorkspacesCtrl"
    });
```

the following server route:

```
router.get("/workspaces", Identity.isAuthenticated, function(request, response) {
    response.render("office/workspaces", {});
});
```

and the following isAuthenticated function:

```
module.exports.isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
    var isAuthenticated = util.isObject(req.identity);
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        return next();
    } else {
        return res.status(401).send();
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

For your task, there is better solution. Use `$httpProvider.interceptors`. From documentation about this solution:

> For purposes of global error handling, authentication, or any kind of
>   synchronous or asynchronous pre-processing of request or
>   postprocessing of responses, it is desirable to be able to intercept
>   requests before they are handed to the server and responses before
>   they are handed over to the application code that initiated these
>   requests.

In your main module create factory:

```
app.factory('myHttpInterceptor', ['$q', '$location', function ($q, $location) {
    return {
        responseError: function(rejection) {
            switch(rejection.status){
                case 401:
                    $location.path("/401");
                break;
                case 0:
                // actions when internet is down
                break;
                default:
                // some default actions
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
}]);
```

and then in app config

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authHttpInterceptor');
});
```

where app is var `app = angular.module(...`

You can read about it in documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http